# Update a subdocument to push a list of sub-subdocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo collection of `AuthorizationRequest` including a list of `AuthorizationRequestComponent` as subdocument. It it possible to add a list of `Comment` for each `AuthorizationRequestComponent`.

In my repository part, I want to insert a list of `Comment` in a specific `AuthorizationRequestComponent` using the following code :

```
public void AddAuthorizationRequestComponentComments(ObjectId id, string componentCode, List<Comment> comments)
{
    var filter = Builders<AuthorizationRequest>.Filter.And(
            Builders<AuthorizationRequest>.Filter.Eq(x => x.TechnicalId, id),
            Builders<AuthorizationRequest>.Filter.ElemMatch(c => c.AuthorizationRequestComponents, c => c.Code == componentCode)
        );

    var update = Builders<AuthorizationRequest>.Update.PushEach(y => y.AuthorizationRequestComponents[0].Comments, comments);

    _authorizationRequestCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
}
```

Unfortunatelly, comments are all time added to the first subdocument of my object. It must be related to the `AuthorizationRequestComponents[0].Comments` or the `ElemMatch`. I found some information on stackoverflow about this, but it's all time using a `Builders<BsonDocument>` instead of the real object.

Comment: Try y.AuthorizationRequestComponents[-1].Comments

Comment: @dnickless it works with the `-1`. Can you please answer the question with a link to documentation, because I don't understand where the `-1` comes from. Thank you.

Comment: I just found the reference again that once tought me this behaviour - see above. So I cannot really take the credits for this one. ;) It's certainly not well documented (you could read through the driver's code, though, if you wanted)...